# Ifstream is not able to read a vector from a file

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, fstream

Hello I am making a simple program which should make an abstract farm with some
 abstract animals but I have got a problem with reading vector from a file. I was translating most of the project and I deleted some I think unimportant functions and constructors. The program works fine when you 1st time load the vector but it fails after 2nd, 3rd... start. It fails when you try to load farm froma before created file. I am sorry for my english.

> this code should be in classes.cpp - i don't know how to write it here

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    #include<iterator>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

//  declaration of class zviera(animal)

    class zviera;

//  class farm

    class farma{ 
    private :

//  meno(name)

        std::string meno;

//  rozloha(size) - perhaps 945.5 * 749.9 meters

        std::pair<double, double> rozloha;

//  vector of friend class zviera(animal)

        std::vector < zviera > zvery;
    public :

//  class zviera(animal) is friend class of farma

        friend class zviera;

//  constructor -----------------------------------------------------

        farma() : meno(""), rozloha(0, 0), zvery(0) {}

//  pridajZviera(addAnimal) to the vector

        void pridajZviera(zviera & z){ zvery.push_back(z); }
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const farma & far);
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, farma & far);
    };

//  the class zviera(animal)

    class zviera{
    private:

//  druh(kind of animal)

        std::string druh;

//  pocet(number of the animals)

        int pocet;

//  sex of the animals

        int pohlavie;
    public:

//  samec(male), samica(female) the sex of the animal

        enum { samec = 0, samica = 1};

//  constructor

        zviera() :druh(""), pocet(0), pohlavie(0){}
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const zviera & zver);
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, zviera & zver);
    };

//  classes.h

    #include"classes.cpp"

//  Writing values of an animal

    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const zviera & zver){
            os << "Kind of animal : " << zver.druh;
            os << "\nNumber of animals : " << zver.pocet;
            os << "\nSex of animal : " << (zver.pohlavie == zver.samec? "male" : "female");
            return os;
        }

//  Setting values of an animal

    std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, zviera & zver){
                std::cout << "Kind : ";
                is >> zver.druh;
                std::cout << "Number : ";
                is >> zver.pocet;
                std::cout << "sex(0 - male, 1 - female) : ";
                is >> zver.pohlavie;
                return is;
            }

//  Writing saved values of a farm

    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const farma & far){
        os << "Name of the farm : " << far.meno;
        os << "\nSize of the farm : " << far.rozloha.first << " * " << far.rozloha.second << "metres." << std::endl;
        os << "Animals on the farm : \n";
        std::vector < zviera >::const_iterator it = far.zvery.begin();
        for (; it != far.zvery.end(); it++){
            os << *it << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }

//  Setting values of a farm 

    std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, farma & far){
        std::cout << "Meno farmy je : ";
        is >> far.meno;
        std::cout << "Rozloha farmy je(a * b metrov) : ";
        is >> far.rozloha.first;
        is >> far.rozloha.second;
        std::cout << " metrov.";
        return is;
    }
```

The **`main.cpp`**

```
    #include"classes.h"

        int main()
    {
        ofstream fout;
        ifstream fin;
        int temp = 0;
        int tmp = 5;
        int tomp = 0;
        string nazov;
        farma far;
        zviera zvero;
        while (cin){
            cout << "Hello would you like to load your farm from a file?(yes - 1, no - 0, end - 2) ";
            cin >> temp;
            switch (temp){
            case 0: 
                cout << "Write a name of a file to save your new farm : ";
                cin >> nazov;
                fout.open(nazov.c_str(), ios_base::out);
                cin >> far;
                fout.write((char*)&far, sizeof far);
                cout << "Would you like to add any animals to your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
                cin >> tmp;
                while (tmp == 1){
                    switch (tmp){
                    case 1:cin >> zvero;
                    far.pridajZviera(zvero);
```

I meam the **problem is probably here**:

```
                    fout.write((char*)&zvero, sizeof zvero);
                    cout << "Would you like to add any animals to your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
                    cin >> tmp;
                        break;
                    default: 
                        break;
                    }
                }
                fout.close();
                cout << "Do you wanna see your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
                cin >> tomp;
                if (tomp == 1){
                    cout << far;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Enter name of the file in which is your farm : ";
                cin >> nazov;
                fin.open(nazov.c_str(), ios_base::in);
```

The problem may be also **here** I think

```
                fin.read((char*)&far, sizeof far);
                while (fin.read((char*)&zvero, sizeof zvero)){
                    far.pridajZviera(zvero);
                }
                cout << far;
                fin.close();
                break;
            case 2: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default: cout << "Wrong value. Enter 0,1 or 2.\n";
                break;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You've defined `iostream` insertion and extraction operators, but you use `write`, which will just write binary data.

Comment: @user3923130 Too much code!  **Please read** about ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  A program you have written may contain infinite problems...but each question you ask should narrow down to just *one* problem that can be demonstrated.  As a simple example: if your problem is with reading files, then *don't include a prompt asking if someone wants to read a file or not*.  Just get it down to one issue at a time, as simple and short as you can make it...you might (ideally) solve your own problem in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` and `write` operations are like `memcpy`, they make a binary image of the object, and don't follow pointers to subobjects.  So you can only use them for *trivially copyable* objects.

`std::vector` and `std::string` are NOT trivially copyable.  (Objects containing these types are NOT trivially copyable either.)  For those, you'll need to fetch and store the length, followed by the data.  For `std::string`, and `std::vector` where the element type is trivially copyable, you can use `read` and `write` to store the data en masse.  Most objects will themselves need to be carefully serialized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i just now understood what you'd tell me. My english is not that good as your and google translate is ... you  know. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reworked - problems solved

> classes.h

```
  #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    #include<iterator>
    #include<fstream>
    class zviera;
    class farma{
    private:
        std::string meno;
        std::pair<double, double> rozloha;
        std::vector < zviera > zvery;
    public:
        friend class zviera;
        farma() : meno(" "), rozloha(0, 0), zvery(0) {}
        void zmenRozlohu(const double & a, const double & b){ rozloha.first = a; rozloha.second = b; }
        void zmenMeno(std::string & s){ meno = s; }
        void pridajZvery(const std::vector < zviera > zv);
        friend std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & fin, farma & far);
        friend std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ofstream & fout, farma & far);
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const farma & far);
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, farma & far);
    };
    class zviera{
    private:
        std::string druh;
        int pocet;
        int pohlavie;
    public:
        friend class farma;
        enum { samec = 0, samica = 1 };
        zviera() :druh(" "), pocet(0), pohlavie(0){}
        friend std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & fin, zviera & zver);
        friend std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ofstream & fout, zviera & zver);
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const zviera & zver);
        friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, zviera & zver);
        void setPohlavie(const int & i){ pohlavie = (pohlavie == i) ? 1 : 0; }
    };
```

> classes.cpp

```
#include"classes.h"
void farma::pridajZvery(const std::vector < zviera > zv){
    zvery.resize(zv.size());
    copy(zv.begin(),zv.end(),zvery.begin());
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const zviera & zver){
    os << "Druh : " << zver.druh;
    os << "\nPocet zvierat : " << zver.pocet;
    os << "\nPohlavie : " << (zver.pohlavie == zver.samec ? "samec" : "samica");
    return os;
}
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, zviera & zver){
    std::cout << "Druh : ";
    is >> zver.druh;
    std::cout << "Pocet : ";
    is >> zver.pocet;
    std::cout << "Pohlavie(0 - samec, 1 - samica) : ";
    is >> zver.pohlavie;
    return is;
}
std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & fin, zviera & zver){
    getline(fin, zver.druh);
    fin >> zver.pocet;
    while (fin.get() != '\n'){
        fin.get();
    }
    fin >> zver.pohlavie;
    while (fin.get() != '\n'){
        fin.get();
    }
    return fin;
}
std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream & fin, farma & far){
    getline(fin, far.meno);
    fin >> far.rozloha.first;
    while (fin.get() != '\n'){
        fin.get();
    }
    fin >> far.rozloha.second;
    while (fin.get() != '\n'){
        fin.get();
    }
    return fin;
}
std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ofstream & fout, farma & far){
    fout << far.meno;
    fout << std::endl;
    fout << far.rozloha.first;
    fout << std::endl;
    fout << far.rozloha.second;
    fout << std::endl;
    return fout;
}
std::ofstream & operator<<(std::ofstream & fout, zviera & zver){
    fout << zver.druh;
    fout << std::endl;
    fout << zver.pocet;
    fout << std::endl;
    fout << zver.pohlavie;
    fout << std::endl;
    return fout;
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const farma & far){
    os << "Nazov farmy : " << far.meno;
    os << "\nFarma ma rozlohu : " << far.rozloha.first << " * " << far.rozloha.second << "metrov." << std::endl;
    os << "Zvierata na farme : \n";
    if (far.zvery.size() <= 0){
        return os;
    }
    std::vector < zviera >::const_iterator it = far.zvery.begin();
    for (; it != far.zvery.end(); it++){
        os << *it << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, farma & far){
    std::cout << "Meno farmy je : ";
    is >> far.meno;
    std::cout << "Rozloha farmy je(a * b metrov) : ";
    is >> far.rozloha.first;
    is >> far.rozloha.second;
    std::cout << " metrov.";
    return is;
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include"classes.h"
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int temp = 0;
    int tmp = 5;
    int tomp = 0;
    int len = 0;
    string nazov;
    zviera zvero;
    while (cin){
        ofstream fout;
        cout << "Hello would you like to load your farm from a file?(yes - 1, no - 0, end - 2) ";
        cin >> temp;
        switch (temp){
        case 0:{
            farma far;
            std::vector < zviera > zve;
            cout << "Write a name of a file to save your new farm : ";
            cin >> nazov;
            fout.open(nazov.c_str(), ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
            cin >> far;
            cout << "Would you like to add any animals to your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
            cin >> tmp;
            while (tmp == 1){
                switch (tmp){
                case 1:cin >> zvero;
                    zve.push_back(zvero);
                    cout << "Would you like to add any animals to your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
                    cin >> tmp;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            len = zve.size();
            fout << len;
            fout << endl;
            for (int x = 0; x < len; x++){
                fout << zve[x];
            }
            fout << far;
            far.pridajZvery(zve);
            fout.close();
            cout << "Do you wanna see your farm?(0 - no, 1 - yes) ";
            cin >> tomp;
            if (tomp == 1){
                cout << far;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            ifstream fin;
            farma kar;
            std::vector < zviera > zvert;
            cout << "Enter name of the file in which is your farm : ";
            cin >> nazov;
            fin.open(nazov.c_str(), ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
            fin >> len;
            while (fin.get() != '\n')
                fin.get();
            zvert.resize(len);
            for (int x = 0; x < len; x++){
                fin >> zvert[x];
            }
            fin >> kar;
            kar.pridajZvery(zvert);
            cout << kar;
            fin.close();
            break;
        }
        case 2: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default: cout << "Wrong value. Enter 0,1 or 2.\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```